# Standardize Column Names from Imported Excel Table

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, typescript

A friend of mine takes orders from customers and customers are basically asked to submit an excel sheet with such fields as item, description, brand, quantity, etc etc. However when customers submit those sheets they do not always come with the same column descriptors so sometimes a sheet will come in with columns like manufacturer instead of brand or the abbreviated 'qty' for quantity, or item description instead of just description just to name a few variations.

I am trying to find a way to basically make a webtool that would allow him to take the table sent to him and make a tool that will standardize those columns without having to go through the copy/paste work as a side tool for me to get some more understanding about programming and algorithms etc.

Basically I am having the excel files imported to the webpage like so

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

type ArrayOfArray = any[][];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-read-excel',
  templateUrl: './read-excel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read-excel.component.css']
})

export class ReadExcelComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit () {

}

  data: ArrayOfArray = [];
  wopts: XLSX.WritingOptions = { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' };
  fileName: string = ' ';

  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (inputFile.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true});
      console.log(typeof binaryString)

      /* grab first sheet */
      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      console.log(workSheetName)
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];


      /* save data */
      this.data = <ArrayOfArray>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, { header: 1, blankrows: true }));

    };
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputFile.files[0]);
  }


}
```

and in the html

```html
<div>
  <h3>File Should Show Here</h3>
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" />
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let column of data">
            <td *ngFor="let val of column">
                {{val}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

In a logical sense I kind of have an idea in mind which I am outlining below

```
if columnheader contains ("brand" or "manufacturer" or "mfg") then place the data within the column inside a new table under the column "brand".
if column header contains ("quantity" or "qty" or "#") then place the data within the column inside the new table under the column "quantity"
```

and so on and so forth. When I import a table this way however, there are a couple of things 1) the tables are importing row by row as opposed to column by column and 2) each row is imported as an array with each item in the array corresponding to a cell within that row. Is there a way to complete the task I have described it. I'm not really looking for a hold my hand do it for me type answer mostly looking to know if it's possible and a general idea of how it may be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to use dedicated for excel files importing tool like [xlsx-import](https://github.com/Siemienik/xlsx-import)?

This will allow you to set Types, for example, a Book type:

```
interface Book {
  Id: number;
  Title: string;
  Author: string;
}
```

And later import by following the configuration:

```
const factory = new ImporterFactory(); 
const importer = await  factory.From(filePath);
const books = importer.GetAllItems<Book>({
    type: 'list',
    worksheet: 'Favourites',
    columns: [
        {index: 1, key: 'Id', mapper: (v: string) => Number.parseInt(v)},
        {index: 2, key: 'Title'},
        {index: 5, key: 'Author'}, 
    ],
    rowOffset: 1, //offset header row
});
```

I have hope this will help you:)